# Bijection $S^1\rightarrow S^1$ inducing bijection between collections of open balls of different sizes

Tags: general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, circles

Let $S^1$ be the circle with circumference $1$. For each $0<r<1$, let $\mathcal{B}_r$ be the collection of open balls of diameter $r$ in $S^1$ (a.k.a.  open arcs of length $r$ along $S^1$).

If $r\ne s$, can there exist a bijection $f: S^1\rightarrow S^1$ which induces a bijection $\mathcal{B}_r \rightarrow \mathcal{B}_s$ (via the canonical map $B\rightarrow f(B)$ for $B\in \mathcal{B}_r$)?

If $r$ and $s$ differ sufficiently, then (assuming $r>s$) there exists a subcover of $\mathcal{B}_r$ with fewer elements than any subcover of $\mathcal{B}_s$, hence the desired bijection cannot exist. For example, if $r={2\over 3}$, and $s = {1\over 3}$, then it is possible to cover $S^1$ with two elements of $B_r$ (take, for example, the two arcs of diameter ${2\over 3}$ centered around two antipodal points on $S^1$); however, $S^1$ cannot be covered with two elements of $B_s$ since the maximal length of a union of two elements of $B_s$ is ${2\over 3}$. Any bijection $f$ satisfying the above properties would need to send covers to covers (of the same cardinality), hence in this case no such bijection can exist.

But what if $r$ and $s$ do not differ sufficiently? Can such a bijection never exist if $r\ne s$, or can it exist if $r$ and $s$ are sufficiently close together?

Comment: Not sure on the definite answer, but if such a bijection existed, it would necessarily be a homeomorphism of $S^1$, because $\mathcal{B}_r$ and $\mathcal{B}_s$ are subbases for the standard topology of $S^1$, hence $f$ is continuous and open by its bijectivity and arc preservation.

Comment: To be more precise, every arc (of small length) is the intersection of two arcs in $\mathcal{B}_r$ (or $\mathcal{B}_s$), so the image (preimage) of our original arc is an intersection of two arcs in $\mathcal{B}_s$ ($\mathcal{B}_r$).